# String to Char Array not working

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, std

I noticed that if my string is empty, the char array does not become empty either. See the below code:

```
std::copy(strUsername.begin(), strUsername.end(), sRecord.m_strUsername);
```

`sRecord.m_strUsername` is a `char[1064]`, but if it is already populated and i try doing a `copy` (or `strcpy`) with `strUsername` as empty, nothing happens, even though I want `sRecord.m_strUsername` to become empty or just become whatever `strUsername` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the zero terminator:

```
std::copy(strUsername.begin(), strUsername.end(), sRecord.m_strUsername);
sRecord.m_strUsername[strUsername.size()] = '\0';
```

or alternatively

```
std::strcpy(sRecord.m_strUsername, strUsername.c_str() );
```

or if you want all "unused" characters of your array to be `\0`:

```
std::copy(strUsername.begin(), strUsername.end(), sRecord.m_strUsername);
std::fill(sRecord.m_strUsername + strUsername.size(), 
          sRecord.m_strUsername + 1064, '\0');
```

The latter is usually not necessary since C-style strings are commonly defined as a range like `[sRecord.m_strUsername[0], first '\0' in the array)`. What comes after the first `\0` usually does not matter unless you want to access that for whatever reason.

The range `[str.begin(), str.end())` only contains all the characters of the string. A C-style string (aka array of `char`) requires an additional `'\0'`-termination character.

With my first and second proposed fix, the range `[sRecord.m_strUsername[0], first '\0' in the array)` will be equal to the characters in `strUsername` as long as the latter does not contain any additional `'\0'`s (something you just cannot easily deal with with C-style strings).

With my third proposed fixed, every character in the array after all the characters from your string will be `\0`.

**Important note:** Before doing any of the above, you need to assert that your string contains at most 1063 characters! If this is not certain, raise some kind of error if the assumption does not hold or use [`std::strncopy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) instead. `strncopy` will basically behave like my third snippet, but you have to zero the last element of your array yourself.

Comment: That didn't work. (gdb) p sRecord.m_strSSOToken
$25 = "QVFJQzV3TTJMWTRTZmN4MEFSNkljSjBxMXdiMVUvRmg5dS95NytZWEI4TExWU1U9QEFBSlRTUUFDTVRBQUFsTkxBQk00TWpnMk5UTTJPRFExTXpRMU1UYzBPREUzQUFKVE1RQUNNRGc9Iw==", '\000' <repeats 111 times>
After the sRecord.m_strUsername[strUsername.size()] = '\0'; where strUsername is empty becomes: (gdb) p sRecord.m_strSSOToken
$27 = "\000VFJQzV3TTJMWTRTZmN4MEFSNkljSjBxMXdiMVUvRmg5dS95NytZWEI4TExWU1U9QEFBSlRTUUFDTVRBQUFsTkxBQk00TWpnMk5UTTJPRFExTXpRMU1UYzBPREUzQUFKVE1RQUNNRGc9Iw==", '\000' <repeats 111 times>

Comment: @suzanaydin Then you need to be more clear what you want to do. Edit your question to clarify. The code I posted does what I thought you were trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Basically, I want the char array to mirror the string in every way. So if the string is empty, i want the char array to be completely empty.

Comment: @suzanaydin *"Is there a way?"* Sure, like `std::fill` or a simple loop. *"Is there a need?"* Probably not since C-style strings are usually defined as a range like `[sRecord.m_strUsername[0], first '\0' in the array)`. What comes behind the first `\0` usually does not matter. *"Basically, I want the char array to mirror the string in every way"* i.e. all unused characters shall be `\0`? I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @suzanaydin there's no such thing as "completely empty" for a `char` array. It's going to contain 1064 characters no matter what, and each of those characters must equal *something*.

Comment: Awesome... thanks for that guys - not the best with C-style strings :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strcpy` which automatically copies the terminating null character as well, and `std::string::c_str`:

```
std::strcpy(sRecord.m_strUsername, strUsername.c_str());
```

So if `strUsername` is empty (`""`), `m_strUsername` will also be equal to `""` after that call.